# How to make the aur package into the archlinux community source?

Tags: package, archlinux, pkgbuild, pacman-package-manager, xmake

I have already uploaded my aur package to the aur.archlinux.org (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xmake/).

How to make the aur package into the archlinux community source?

I want to run command `pacman -S xmake` to install my package.

Who can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a maintainer in AUR, I can answer that the only way is to become a member of the famous **trusted users of Arch Linux**. Which is kinda **hard do integrate** if you **only have one package** (just saw your repository).

To quote [the official Arch Linux team](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trusted_Users):

> **The minimum requirements to becoming a TU are as follows:**
>
> - know basic shell scripting
> - maintain a few packages in AUR with clean, high-quality PKGBUILDs
>     basic community involvement (mailing list, forums, IRC)
> - know Google-Fu
> - a general idea of the kind of packages you want to maintain (basically, why do you want to become TU?)
>
> **Even though you could become a TU by merely fulfilling those minimum requirements, the people judging you during voting might expect more of you. Such as:**
>
> - involvement in the bug tracker (reporting, research, info)
> - patches for Arch projects
> - involvement in a few open-source projects (even if they are your own)

**In between your package have a big problem and I marked it as out-of-date because of the following:**

1. According to [Arch packaging standard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_packaging_standards):

   > Packages should **never** be installed to /usr/local

You should install all your files under `/usr/share/{pkgName}/*` according to the standard.

Comment: Thank you very much and I have modified the installation path. :)